# In how many ways can the 26 letters in the alphabet...?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can the 26 letters in the alphabet be arranged so b be somewhere to the left of e?

---

Basically, all the permutations in which the letter 'b' comes before the letter 'e'

---

How can I do this?

Comment: There are $26!$ different arrangements, and in half of them 'b' comes before 'e'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $26!$ different arrangements, in half of which 'b' comes before 'e'.

---

Alternatively, you can multiply the following:

- Number of ways to choose places for 'b' and 'e', which is $\binom{26}{2}$
- Number of ways to arrange the remaining letters, which is $(26-2)!$

Comment: how do you know that " in half of which 'b' comes before 'e'."

Comment: @KracX: Because it can only come before or after, and these $2$ options are equally likely.

Comment: @KracX Because we can pair the different arrangements up, two by two, where two arrangements go together if the only difference between them is that 'b' and 'e' have swapped places. This way every arrangement gets one, and only one pair-mate, and in each pair, exactly one of the arrangements have 'b' before 'e'.

Comment: But due to the completely unnecessary down-vote, I will remove this answer!!!

Comment: its alright ill mark it correct soon